# HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected exception Android- Testing

Tags: android, calabash

I am using Calabash to test my UI. What i am doing is to have access to Share Preferences following this:

https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/documentation/ruby_api.md

But sometimes I get this issue....

```
Error:

When I use share preferences                                                          features/step_definitions/basic_steps.rb:13
      HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected (HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected)
      ./features/step_definitions/basic_steps.rb:14:in `/^I use share preferences$/'
      features/my_first.feature:7:in `When I use share preferences'

*******************
Code: 

When /^I use share preferences$/  do
    set_preferences("pref",{:number =>"332710"})
end
************
```

Comment: The message says Calabash lost connection with your app. Most probably your app crashed at that step.

Comment: The app didn't crash, I think that there is an issue in this library using Strings in the Shared Preferences....